# php insert prepared stmt

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, prepared-statement

My code looks like:

```
$sql_ = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
        $sql_->execute();
        $user = $sql_->fetchAll();

        $sql_insert_blog = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO
                                              blog
                                              (blog_title,blog_author,blog_content,blog_tags,blog_create,blog_update)
                                              VALUES
                                              (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)");
        $sql_insert_blog->execute(array(
                                        ":1"=>$title,
                                        ":2"=>$author,
                                        ":3"=>$content,
                                        ":4"=>$tags,
                                        ":5"=>$date_create,
                                        ":6"=>$date_update
                                        ));
```

So the first sql statement is to proof if the database coneccion is active. It works when i use

```
print_r($user)
```

Th second one is the statement thats not been executed.

I have a controller that calls this function on a model, and gives all the info from the form to this function like

```
function newBlogEntry()


{

$title = $_POST["input_blog_title"];
$author = $_POST["input_blog_author"];
$content = $_POST["input_blog_content"];
$tags = $_POST["input_blog_tags"];
$date_create = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
$date_update = $date_create;

$this->model->newBlogEntry($title,$author,$content,$tags,$date_create,$date_update);


}
```

and the function on this model is actually called. i can select all users from db.

i allready checked all the parameters, and also every parameter can be null so, even if the form is emtpy it should be a insert in the database(This is just for testing).

But there is no entry in the database...

So my question is: what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this produce any error messages? Check your server's `error.log` file to be sure.

Comment: @Darwin Parse error: parse error, expecting `"identifier (T_STRING)"' or `"namespace (T_NAMESPACE)"' or `"\\ (T_NS_SEPARATOR)"' in

Comment: Sorry forgot to put exception in the catch stmt... i get no exception..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you pass NULL for the two date fields and real data for all the rest?

Comment: now it works!!! the date is in this format i gues its wrong... -> "12/05/2015 12:15:42 am"

Comment: Changed the dateformat to from date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time()) to date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time())

Comment: Try `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`; I think MySQL assumes a 24-hour clock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that MySQL doesn't like your date values. The default format for dates-as-strings in MySQL is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, according to the docs; a string that looks like this will automatically be parsed as a date.

Answer (score 0):

use `(?,?,?,?,?,?)` instead of `(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)`
and

```
$sql_insert_blog->execute(array($title, $author, $content, $tags, $date_create, $date_update));
```

and
dates should be strings with `Y-m-d H:i:s` php `date()` format